# AngularJS referencing sub-pages behave differently on different browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat

I have a SPA built on AngularJS. The development was done using Brackets (with its internal server) and everything is working as required.

Now, I deployed the application into a Tomcat server and am experiencing problems referencing sub-pages, being these problems different depending on the used browser (MS-Edge, MS-IE, Google Chrome, Safari tests not started as yet).

Assuming that the root is located at `/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/webapps/MyApp` (here the `Index.html` is) and then there is a sub-folder called `pages` and another called `modals`. I tried:

- `pages/modals/Error.html`,
- `/pages/modals/Error.html` (which **did work** with Brackets!!),
- `#/pagesmodals/Error.html`.

All modals are open using a `factory` that includes the following piece of code:

```
            modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl : p_Template,
                size        : l_size,
                sample      : { module: function () {
                                                        return sampleVar;
                                                    }
                              }
        });
```

Again, whenever I change method, things that worked with one browser stop working while in other browser start working.

Comment: Have you enabled HTML5 mode?

Comment: You mean in my code or in TOMCAT? Either way, I read about it but not sure how to do it, what the impact is and where.

Comment: HTML5 mode in Angular code?

Comment: Note. How and where should I do it, and what would be the implications?

Comment: I just checked the documentation and... Not clear to me how to do it (this is the very first application I developed in AngularJS). Could you provide some simple guidance? Thanks in advance!!!